# Is a smooth function characterized up to translation by its discrete pieces?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth, bounded functions, and suppose that for any finite set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, there is some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $x \in X$, $f(x) = g(x + t)$. (I.e., $f$ and $g$ have the same finite restrictions up to translation.) Does it follow that $f$ and $g$ are identical up to some translation?

(For my application I really want the answer to be "yes", so if there are other nice conditions I can impose on $f$ and $g$ to get that answer, that would also be great to know.)

Comment: As @vadim123's example shows this is not an equivalence relation!

Comment: True! I've [reposted a revised version of the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525965/is-a-smooth-function-characterized-up-to-translation-by-its-discrete-pieces-re). I hope I got the formulation right this time...

Comment: Your formulation was not "wrong". It's just a subtle point you maybe have overlooked.

Comment: It was wrong just in the sense that I didn't ask the question that I meant to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let $g(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\le 0\\ e^{-1/x^2} & x>0\end{cases}$, and let $f(x)=0$.  Any $X$ you like for $f$, has a translate into the negative reals where $f,g$ agree.  $g(x)$ is constructed to be $C^\infty$ everywhere; it is also bounded above by $1$ (and below by $0$).

A condition you need to impose is that $f,g$ are equal to their Taylor series everywhere.  I'm not sure if that's enough, but it's a start.

Comment: Oh, shoot, I misstated my question. I meant to say "and conversely"—and the converse doesn't hold in this case, since $g$ takes positive values but $f$ doesn't. I'm still pretty new here: what's the etiquette for changing my question after it's been answered?

Comment: I'd recommend reposting, with the changes there; if you change the question as written I'll need to delete my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've posted a revised question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525965/is-a-smooth-function-characterized-up-to-translation-by-its-discrete-pieces-re).