# Is a smooth function characterized up to translation by its discrete pieces? (revised)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth, bounded functions, and suppose that for any finite set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, there is some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $x \in X$, $f(x) = g(x + t)$. And suppose the converse also holds. (So $f$ and $g$ have the same finite restrictions up to translation.) Does it follow that $f$ and $g$ are identical up to some translation?

(For my application I really want the answer to be "yes", so if there are other nice conditions I can impose on $f$ and $g$ to get that answer, that would also be great to know.)

(This question is a fixed version of [this original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525933/is-a-smooth-function-characterized-up-to-translation-by-its-discrete-pieces).)